# How to dynamically import clusterApiUrl in next js

Tags: web3.js, solana-wallet-adapter, nextjs, solana-wallet-adaptor

I want to dynamically import clusterApiUrl from `"@solana/web3.js"` using `next/dynamic`, but I get an error `"clusterApiUrl is not a function"`.

This is how I import it:

```
const clusterApiUrl = dynamic(
  () => import("@solana/web3.js").then((mod) => mod.clusterApiUrl ),
  {
    ssr: false,
  }
);
```

and I use clusterApiUrl like this: `const endpoint = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl(network), [network]);`
I'm trying to reduce my bundle size

Comment: I'm not familiar with NextJS dynamic, but are you sure it can be used this way? The docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import) only show it being used for React components

Comment: yeah I later discovered it cant be used to import functions

How do you suggest I reduce the import size of clusterApiUrl?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, Next should already be optimising the bundle to only import what's needed. If you use less of `@solana/web3.js` you should see a smaller bundle, with it getting larger as you import more. Can you update the question to include some bundle size numbers and exactly what code you're using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same principle to import external libraries using `import()` at the point where that module is needed. Architect your code such that `clusterApiUrl` is only needed in a codepath that's inaccessible to the server renderer (eg. in an effect, or an event handler).

See ‘[with external libraries](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-external-libraries)’ in the Next.js ‘dynamic imports’ documentation.

Answer (score 1):

this is the typescript signature of next.js dynamic

```
function dynamic<P = {}>(dynamicOptions: DynamicOptions<P> | Loader<P>, options?: DynamicOptions<P>)
                     // this is the return value
                     : React.ComponentType<P>
```

it should return a React component. You could try this

```
export const WrapperComponent = (props) => {
  // Make instance here 
  const clusterApi = useMemo(() => clusterApiUrl,[]);  

  // Do whatever you want here with the clusterApi

  return <div>Something</div>;
}
```

then dynamically import the WrapperComponent